# How to enable mod_http_upload in ejabberd server?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I need to enable `mod_http_upload` on my jabber-server, but, if I add the string:

```
mod_http_upload: {}
```

in the `modules` section of `ejabberd.yml` the server crashes and will not start until I remove this string.

Answer (score 2):

What error message does it show? In ejabberd.yml it is important the line indentation. For example, this is correct:

```
modules:
  mod_http_upload: {}
```

This is incorrect:

```
modules:
mod_http_upload: {}
```

and throws that error:

```
14:30:29.207 [error] Cannot load /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml:
 Syntax error on line 756 at position 3:
 did not find expected key
```